# magento 2 system logs

Tags: magento2

Can someone can explain me this errors in system.log ?

```
[2017-01-27 09:04:22] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4c6bda8894dd89ac21681d9ff15934ffc and handles default, catalog_product_view, catalog_product_view_id_20, catalog_product_view_sku_The%20Duffle, catalog_product_view_type_configurable: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles 1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'productNameCustom' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.price' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.review', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.price' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.attributes.dimension' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product_tabs' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.attributes.instructions' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product_tabs' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.price.final' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.sku', but their parents are different: 'product.info.price' and 'product.info.stock.sku' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.social' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product.info.extrahint' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'view.addto.compare' tries to reorder itself towards 'view.addto.wishlist', but their parents are different: 'product.info.addto' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:20] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:22] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_435d9b25a1c4d8320af798261db18c2f4 and handles default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_layered, catalog_category_view_type_layered_without_children, catalog_category_view_id_8: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.INFO: Cyclic dependency in merged layout for handle: 2columns-left [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.INFO: Cyclic dependency in merged layout for handle: 2columns-left [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4a7ccd8094436548b564a588f6303121c and handles 2columns-left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'productNameCustom' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product_tabs' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'productNameCustom' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product_tabs' tries to reorder itself towards 'alert.urls', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.attributes.dimension' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product_tabs' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.attributes.instructions' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product_tabs' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:26:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'productNameCustom' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.social' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.price' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.review', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and 'product.info.price' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.attributes.dimension' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product_tabs' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.attributes.instructions' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product_tabs' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.price.final' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.sku', but their parents are different: 'product.info.price' and 'product.info.stock.sku' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.social' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'product.info.extrahint' and 'product.info.main' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'view.addto.compare' tries to reorder itself towards 'view.addto.wishlist', but their parents are different: 'product.info.addto' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:09] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'customer'. [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:14] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-27 11:27:15] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Comment: They mainly seem to be layout XML errors, as to how to debug them you'll probably need to go through each line and find the references.

Comment: but in general everything works good

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that to, I'm sure some of the errors are from the base theme as well as I recall seeing them before I even started any customisations. To check that try clearing your logs, setting the theme to your parent theme, then loading a few pages and checking the logs again. If they are coming from your parent theme I don't think there is a lot you can do.